# how i can make content of file as output of command?

Tags: linux, file, command-line, solaris

i have a file contain list of path now i want to execute command on each line example :-

```
file name : rawabdeh
command : command

file contain:-

path/no/1/
path/no/2/
path/no/3/
```

i want to do the following :

```
command path/no/1/
command path/no/2/
command path/no/3/
```

Comment: You have asked 5 questions but have not accepted a single answer.

Comment: i will do now ..... becouse i am busy ... but thank you for this Alert

Comment: What operating system? What shell?

Comment: my operating system is solaris

Comment: As far as I remember Solaris!=Linux. Why not update your tags?

Comment: ok i will do thanks for advice me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read path <&3
do
  command "$path" 3<&-
done 3<rawabdeh
```

This will execute command on each of the paths -- is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i will try it now .... put the path in the same file "rawabdeh" ...each line of file is path

Comment: the following result accour for all line in file ...ksh[2]: /var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core/: cannot execute
ksh[2]: /var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees/: cannot execute
ksh[2]: /var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/merchantserver/: cannot execute
ksh[2]: /var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/2ds/: cannot execute
ksh[2]: /var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/iris/: cannot execute

Comment: Did you erase the first word on the third line? It should be your command. Anyway, paste your complete script so we can say what's wrong.